# JQuery not catching dropdown value

Tags: php, html, jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm making an API interface for scheduling package pickups. The API requires the number of packages, among other things. My project manager said he needed the number of packages to be a dropdown list. Now trying to grab just the package count from the form isn't working, even though it works for my other dropdowns.

My PHP code for generating the dropdown:

```
<select name="package_count" id="package_count" class="form-control form-inps">
                                <?php for ($i=1; $i<26; $i++) {
                                    if ($i !== 1) {
                                        echo "<option value='${i}'>${i}</option>";
                                    } else {
                                        echo "<option selected='selected' value='${i}'>${i}</option>";
                                    }
                                } ?>
                            </select>
```

The code to catch it for the API call:

```
info.package_count = $("#package_count").val();
```

For reference, here's my code for generating dropdown of customer State:

```
<select id="state" name="state" class="form-control form-inps">
                            <?php $customerState = $customer_id->state;
                                foreach ($categories as $abbr=>$full) {
                                if ($abbr !== $customerState && strtolower($full) !== strtolower($customerState)) {
                                    echo "<option value='${abbr}'>${full}</option>";
                                } else {
                                    echo "<option value='${abbr}' selected='selected'>${full}</option>";
                                }
                            }?>
                        </select>
```

And the code to catch it:

```
info.state = $("#state").val();
```

Despite what seems like identical structures, the State gets caught but the package count doesn't:

```
city: 
"REDACTED"
company: 
""
date: 
"2023-03-17"
earliest: 
"13:00"
latest: 
"17:00"
name: 
"REDACTED"
package_count: 
""
shipping_direction: 
undefined
shipping_provider: 
undefined
state: 
"REDACTED"
street: 
"REDACTED"
street2: 
""
zip: 
"REDACTED"
```

Any ideas why state works but not packagecount?

Comment: Also yes I know that the "if 1 selected" statement isn't needed, I just added that in to see if it made a difference by having it be as mirrored as possible to state

Comment: did you check the HTML output? It will focus your question to html or php solution.

Comment: Yes, the sample output is from calling console.log(info)

Comment: that's the javascript output, I mean the HTML output

Comment: Check if any of the options appear as selected, if not the val will be undefined.

Comment: yes I see what you mean now, but the HTML comes out fine. all the number options are there, with listed values and the 1 listed as selected

Answer (score 0):

Your try to loop with multiple option select its wrong method

|| `echo "<option selected='selected' value='${i}'>${i}</option>";`

its also the final value as selected default last value

Try this

```js
$("#package_count").change(function(){
 var val= $("#package_count option:selected").val();
  $('#result').html(val);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="package_count" id="package_count" class="form-control form-inps">
<option value="1" >1</option>
<option value="2" >2</option>
<option value="3" >3</option>
<option value="4" >4</option>
<option value="5" >5</option>
<option value="6" >6</option>
<option value="7" >7</option>
<option value="8" >8</option>
<option value="9" >9</option>
<option value="10" >10</option>

  </select>
  
  <p id="result" style="color:red;font-size:14px"></p>
```